# How to select two tables data in php?

Tags: php

Requirement:-> I want to select two tables data on the basis of tin. i have date in tin from 23-DEC-2017 to 29-DEC-2017. I want to set `$stmtc['TIN']='A'`

where it does not get any date in tin.

```
$query = "SELECT dt,entusr, attremark, empcode, compcode FROM NPINOUTSCR where entusr='".$entusr."' and empcode='".$empcode."' and compcode='".$compcode."' ";

    $result = oci_parse($con,$query);
    $exe = oci_execute($result);

    while($row= oci_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $stmtb['DT']=$row['DT'];
        $stmtb['ENTUSR']=$row['ENTUSR'];
        $stmtb['ATTREMARK']=$row['ATTREMARK'];
        $stmtb['EMPCODE']=$row['EMPCODE'];
        $stmtb['COMPCODE']=$row['COMPCODE'];
        $stmtb['remark'] = array();
        echo $stmtb['DT'];

            $q1 = "select to_char(tin, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mm:ss') as tin, to_char(tout, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mm:ss') as tout from npinout where compcode='".$compcode."' and empcode='".$empcode."' and to_char(tin, 'MON-YYYY') ='".$date."' and trunc(tin)='".$stmtb['DT']."' ORDER BY tin " ;

            $rs1=oci_parse($con,$q1);
            $ex1=oci_execute($rs1); 

            while($row1= oci_fetch_assoc($rs1))
            {

                    if($stmtb['ATTREMARK']=='')
                    {
                        $stmtc['TIN']="A";
                        $stmtc['TOUT']="A";
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        $stmtc['TIN']=$row1['TIN'];
                        $stmtc['TOUT']=$row1['TOUT'];
                    } 

                array_push($stmtb['remark'],$stmtc);
            }

        array_push($final,$stmtb);      

    }
    echo json_encode($final);
```

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Unclear about what db language you want to use and not specific about condition you want to perform. Its a left join or right join...

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the [MySQL JOIN manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the database sql, but you can always try if(statement,true,false) in your query:

```
"SELECT if(tin = defaultValue,'A',tin),..."
```

Also it seems redundant to even run the query if previous `$stmtb['ATTREMARK'] = ''`